# Java 8 JSTL and saxParseException

Tags: java, xml, java-8, jstl, sax

I am running Java 1.8.0_131, also tried with 121, with Tomcat 7 and 8 (tried both).
The application uses jstl and the jstl jar is included in tomcat_home/lib directory.
When the application starts it throws this exception.

```
    WARNING: Failed to scan JAR [jndi:/localhost/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar] from WEB-INF/lib
java.io.IOException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: XML parsing error on file jndi:/localhost/tba/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar: (line 44, col 14)
```

Caused by this

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 44; columnNumber: 14; JAXP00010003: The length of entity "[xml]" is "2" that exceeds the "1" limit set by "system property".
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure you are using java 1.8.0_131, I am thinking you might have hit https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8028111, also do check, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/limits/limits.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/limits/using.html

Comment: yeah I get it with 131 and 121 but using 1.7 it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because someone had set these two [system properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/limits/limits.html)

```
jdk.xml.totalEntitySizeLimit=1
jdk.xml.maxGeneralEntitySizeLimit=1
```

Setting the properties to [more sane values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/limits/using.html) fixed the problem